# How to filter using get_queryset in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Currently, the API I'm pulling is as such:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/locs/data/2
```

and the output is as such:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "date": "2019-01-07",
    "hour": null,
    "measurement": null,
    "location": 6
}
```

What I want is actually filtering by the `location` value, so from the API url above, I would love to pull all the data that is from `location: 2`. How can I achieve that?

What I have so far:
**views.py**

```py
class LocationDataView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = LocationDataSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = LocationData.objects.all()
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        queryset = queryset.filter(location=pk)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

and **urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'locs', views.LocationListView, 'locs')
router.register(r'locs/data', views.LocationDataView, 'locs/data')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),

    path('locs/forecast-data/',
         views.getForecastData, name='forecast-data'),
]
```

My question is that, how can I access the `pk` for the location?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the `retrieve` function in the `LocationDataView`.

```
class LocationDataView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializers = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializers.data)
```

And in urls.py

```
...
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'locs', views.LocationListView, 'locs')
router.register(r'locs/<int:pk>', views.LocationDataView, 'locs/data')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need the answer and not sure if my solution is good but what I have done is access the kwargs inside the query function.

As explained in the other answer you need a `retrieve` or `get` function where the request can be used. I am using generics from Django Rest

```
    class YourClassName(RetrieveAPIView):
        serializer_class = LocationDataSerializer
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
        def get_queryset(self):
            return LocationData.objects.filter(location=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        def retrieve(request, self, *args, **kwargs):
            list = self.get_queryset()
            serializer = self.get_serializer(list, many = True)
```